# How to get nested array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to filter based on condition in javascript.
If the
  `min` is present and `amt > min`, get `whole obj` else, 
   `remove that particular object in the obj`

```
function getItem(obj){
  return
   obj.filter(e=>e.hasOwnProperty("min")?e.amt>e.min:e);

}
var obj1=[{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "SG"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
}]
var obj2=[{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 500,
  "cn" : "SG"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
}]
```

Expected Output:
var result = getItem(obj1);

```
[{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
}]
```

var result = getItem(obj2);

```
[{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 500,
  "cn" : "SG"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
},{
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn" : "TH"
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution i tried

```js
function getItem(obj) {
  
  return !('min' in obj) || obj.amt>obj.min ;
  
}
var obj1 = [{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "SG"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}]
var obj2 = [{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 500,
  "cn": "SG"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}]

var result1 = obj1.filter(getItem);
var result2 = obj2.filter(getItem);
console.log('result1',result1);
console.log('result2',result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence of `min`, if not return the object else check if it is greater than `amt`.

```js
var obj1 = [{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "SG"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}]
var obj2 = [{
  "id": "name",
  "min": 300,
  "amt": 500,
  "cn": "SG"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}, {
  "id": "others",
  "amt": 200,
  "cn": "TH"
}];

const res1 = obj1.filter(({
  min,
  amt
}) => {
  return !min || (amt > min);
});

console.log(res1);

const res2 = obj2.filter(({
  min,
  amt
}) => {
  return !min || (amt > min);
});

console.log(res2);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, is it possible to do with single filter

Comment: @Senthil - You can combine two arrays `obj1` and `obj2` into one and then apply filter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want to apply the condition `amt > min` if and only if the object contains `min`. If the object doesn't contain `min`, then return the whole object.

In that case, `getItem` should look like this:

```
const getItem = arrayOfObjects => arrayOfObjects.filter(obj => {
    if (obj['min']) {
        if (obj['amt'] > obj['min']) return true
    } else {
        return true
    }
})
```